# Java FileOutputStream, write doubles to file

Tags: java, stream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

After some googling I believe its best to raise the issue here;

Trying to write a program which reads double-values form a .txt-file(no problem), writes them to a binary file and then read them back in (from binary file).

Im using FileInputStream/FileOutputStream for this matter, which I believe is the wrong way to do it (but Im awfully **green** at this and only instructed with these two)

But these methods only read/write int-values, or more correct, the first 8 bits of the int attached/returned.

I know that double's are 64 bits, so that immediately opposes a problem. If Im using the wrong classes I would happily change them.

Cheers!

Comment: Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128116/java-serialize-double) could help.

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with using FileIn/OutputStream directly, wrapping them in  DataIn/OutputStream is easier as it lets you read/write many common types.

Answer (score 1):

Although not impossible, using relatively raw streams for this task is not the easiest way.  [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) has writeDouble / readDouble methods that I think do exactly what you want - ie, dumping primitive values "as such" in a file and reading them back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your FileOutputStream in an ObjectOutputStream and your FileInputStream in an ObjectInputStream.These classes have methods writing/reading Java primitives.